# How about a feature to request a revision on a response and/or downvote?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, down-votes

Is there any mechanism to appeal or ask for a revision if someone from the community downvote a question?

What I am interested in is in a mechanism to set an answer as potentially wrong or potentially correct (other than voting of course) after a revision process. In chess there is a sign for this, when I game is reviewed by players they can say: "!?"=dubious or "?"= bad, "??"= really bad or "!"=good, "!!"=really good.

By requesting the revision of the community, those who participate will decide by marking one or more of the answers as "!?", "?","!" or "!!" and to make this not requested so often we could make it work like the bounty where it cost some of my reputation to request this revision.

Comment: Re your edit, not sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate and explain it better?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Can you take a look now?

Comment: Yes I did and even more confused. Bounty is set on a question, not answer, and while it can be used to get attention what you said makes little sense.

Comment: I am not saying it should exactly the same as the bounty. I am referring to create a feature to work in a similar way to review the answers.

Comment: "Downvoted answers appeal review queue"? That does sounds interesting, but I highly doubt it will be done. Editing bump to the front page meaning new set of eyes will have a look and if indeed it's a good answer, it will get upvotes. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, that queue does sound interesting, but you know it would lead to a lot of downvote piling-on, magnifying the effect of a single downvote.

Comment: Of course, probably would also lead to a lot of sympathy upvotes.

Comment: That would depend on the mechanism applied to avoid something like "sympathy". As Engineer I am more interested in truth than sympathy.

Comment: I just restructure the question for community revision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing to do by far is to improve your post. If someone left you a comment with a suggestion, consider it carefully. If not, take a critical look at it yourself.

There is no way to specifically ask down voters to review their votes, and the community does not like that idea in general. But when you improve your post, you can get up votes which will counteract any down votes... and you may get those down votes reversed, too.

If someone left a comment, also; you can reply to them with the @-syntax, which will notify them. For example, to @-reply me:

```
@AndrewBarber I improved my post. Can you check it out now?
```

Comment: To avoid criticism, do nothing, say nothing, and be nothing.
Elbert Hubbard